# Attempting to find bundle for my custom Quartz Composer plugin

Tags: xcode, nsbundle, quartz-composer

I am writing my own Quartz Composer plugin and I would like to load GLSL shaders, textures, etc. from my QC plugin's bundle.  The problem is that it appears that I am getting my loading application's (the QC runtime app) bundle instead.  I tried iterating through all of my bundles but this didn't seem to work either.

Is there any easy way to access my QC bundle directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[NSBundle mainBundle]` gives you the application bundle, not the plugin bundle.

From within a plugin's class, you could do this to get the plugin's bundle:

```
NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
```